# how to start chrome debugger since the very beginning of page loading

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, debugging, loading

I would like to start debugging javascript before the load event at each time each part of the javascript is obtained from the server.

I know that chrome can debug event triggered by the load page event.
But if I'm not wrong during the loading of the page, the obtained javascript from the browser is executed before the load page event. (and some part can be executed again latter if they are saved in load page event)

Is it possible and how to do so?

Comment: Open the debugger, set your break point, then reload the page?

Comment: Yes indeed it works, I didn't know that I could open javascript in the html main file by going on "source" tab in chrome debugger and selecting the main file, so I didn't know how to add a breakpoint. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For this you can write 'debugger' in your Javascript code and then open debugger in chrome and refresh page, now your page will stop on debugger and you can debug step by step.